# Alpha animation for BitmapFont

Tags: java, android, animation, fonts, libgdx

I am new to libgdx and want to know if there is an easy way to alpha animate a BitmapFont I am currently using `FreeTypeFont` to generate my font style and if I call:

`bitmapfont.setColor(1,1,1,alphahere)`

then it would render my text back to normal removing the style from my FreeTypeFont.

How can I animate the bitmap font with out removing its style from the FreeType?

Comment: If no one else answers the question by then, I have an answer for you when I get home to my PC.

Comment: So ? Did you find a solution ? Did you try my solution ? If that didn't work, what did you observe ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change your font color by using a **`Label()`**;

In your the creation of your class you'll have :

```
labelStyle = new LabelStyle(yourFreeTypeFont, new Color(1,1,1,1));
label = new Label("Your Text", labelStyle);
```

And in the `render()` you'll have :

```
labelStyle.fontColor = new Color(1,1,1,0);
label.setStyle(labelStyle);
```

By this method you can off course change any channels, not only the alpha

---

**Edit : Second method**

Now that I think of it, as a Label() is an actor, there is an even better way to change the alpha channel.
You can instantly change the alpha value of the label with :

```
label.addAction(Actions.alpha(floate alphaValue));
```

Or you can make a progressive change with :

```
label.addAction(Actions.alpha(float alphaValue, float duration));
```